# Resource not found: Paypal verification (email, firstname, lastname) rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, controller

My `email`, `firstname`, `lastname` all work on the paypal website for verification: https://paypal-sdk-samples.herokuapp.com/adaptive_accounts/get_verified_status

Im having a problem after I submit my form I'm automatically calling the `email`, `firstname`, `lastname` in my controller before I set them to input boxes to make sure I have everything set up correctly. Is there something more I must do in order for this account to be verified and have status??

I get `Resource not found:` after submitting

Maybe the reason is because the LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]], Also seems like users is being called too many times? `SELECT "users"` Thank You!!!!

**Error Log:**

```
Processing by VerificationsController#create as 
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0S7n8LHhtb5zdAfmv9/BXdNtkeiBNAcvWx2lC3gvmrndUNz4V/Cq+p3yAuQY8vggYqIGm5DJGUFUpMpWxJyg5Q==", "verification"=>{"paypal_email"=>"vampiricbeef@gmail.com", "paypal_firstname"=>"", "paypal_lastname"=>""}, "commit"=>"verify", "id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY created_at DESC
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/3/paypal_verification
Completed 302 Found in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

**verificationsController:**

```rails
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    # @verification = current_user.verification.create(verification_params)
    @verification = current_user.create_verification(verification_params)



require 'paypal-sdk-adaptiveaccounts'
@api = PayPal::SDK::AdaptiveAccounts::API.new( :device_ipaddress => "127.0.0.1" )

# Build request object
@get_verified_status = @api.build_get_verified_status({
  :emailAddress => "current_user.verification.paypal_email",
  :matchCriteria => "NONE" })

# Make API call & get response
@get_verified_status_response = @api.get_verified_status(@get_verified_status)

# Access Response
if @get_verified_status_response.success?
  @get_verified_status_response.accountStatus
  @get_verified_status_response.countryCode
  @get_verified_status_response.userInfo
else
  @get_verified_status_response.error
end

status = params[:accountStatus]
verification = Verification.find(params[:emailAddress])

if status != "VERIFIED" || @get_verified_status_response.error

  redirect_to edit_user_registration_path(current_user)
    verification.update_attributes paypal_verified: false
    verification.destroy

  elsif status == "VERIFIED"
    redirect_to edit_user_registration_path(current_user)
  verification.update_attributes paypal_verified: true

else
redirect_to edit_user_registration_path(current_user)
    verification.update_attributes paypal_verified: false
    verification.destroy
end

end



private
        def verification_params
            params.require(:verification).permit(:user_id, :paypal_firstname, :paypal_lastname, :paypal_email, :paypal_verified)
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where you should change where you call user attributes

```
@get_verified_status = @api.build_get_verified_status({
  :emailAddress => "@user.paypal_email", # or "current_user.paypal_email"
  :matchCriteria => "NAME",
  :firstName => "@user.paypal_firstname",
  :lastName => "@user.paypal_lastname" })
```

Comment: The problem is the nil in user.. an array maybe that I dont understand how to fix.. but once this user nil problem is gone then It should work!!! so sad!!